# File input java, scanner using if.. else statment. error provided

Tags: java

Ok guys so i am trying to read in from 1 out of 3 files normally with out the `if` ... `else` clause

just `Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze1.txt"));` would run the problem, but i want the user to select what maze he/she would like to run

```
public class Main {
    private static Scanner myScanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Please Enter 1,2 or 3 to pick the different maze you would like being solved.");
        Scanner myScannerinput = new Scanner(System.in);



        int Mazenumber = myScannerinput.nextInt();

        if(Mazenumber == 1){
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze1.txt"));
        }
        else if(Mazenumber == 2){
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze2.txt"));
        }
        else if(Mazenumber == 3){
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze3.txt"));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You did not choose one of the 3 mazes");
        }



        int numRows = myScanner.nextInt();
        int numCols = myScanner.nextInt();
        myScanner.nextLine();

        int startX = 0;
        int startY = 0;'
```

Please Enter 1,2 or 3 to pick the different maze you would like being solved.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

Comment: The line `myScanner.nextLine();` should be generating a compiler error, because `myScanner`'s scope each time is only within the `if` and `else if` blocks.

Comment: Notice that you've declared myScanner as an automatic local 3 times, with none of those declarations accessible outside the `if` ladder.

Comment: @rgettman - It doesn't create a compile error because he's also declared myScanner as a static.

Comment: (You shouldn't make variables that are essentially local to a method "static".  They should be declared *inside* the method.)

Comment: @HotLicks I didn't see the `static` variable `myScanner` before.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @rgettman - Yeah, it was easy to miss, being in a very unexpected place.

Answer (score 1):

don't create individual new Scanner inside the if condition. Create one Scanner before the if condition and assign the file based on your preference.

```
        int Mazenumber = myScannerinput.nextInt();
        Scanner myScanner =null;
        if(Mazenumber == 1){
            myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze1.txt"));
        }
        else if(Mazenumber == 2){
            myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze2.txt"));
        }
        else if(Mazenumber == 3){
            myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze3.txt"));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You did not choose one of the 3 mazes");
        }
        if(myScanner!=null){
           int numRows = myScanner.nextInt();
           int numCols = myScanner.nextInt();
           myScanner.nextLine();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 int Mazenumber = myScannerinput.nextInt();

        if(Mazenumber == 1){
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze1.txt"));
        }
        else if(Mazenumber == 2){
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze2.txt"));
        }
        else if(Mazenumber == 3){
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("maze3.txt"));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You did not choose one of the 3 mazes");
        }
```

Use

```
Scanner myScanner;
int Mazenumber = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Choose 1, 2 or 3");
    Mazenumber = myScannerinput.nextInt();
    if(Mazenumber >=1 && Mazenumber <=3) {
         String fileName = "maze"+Mazenumber+".txt";
        myScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } else {
           System.out.println("You did not choose one of the 3 mazes");      
     }

} while(Mazenumber>3 && Mazenumber <1);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Main.main(Main.java:33)

The exception is because, you've declared `Scanner myScanner` inside `if-else` block.

Comment: That won't compile. You can only do the URL trick if some statement or block comes after it. Besides, let's not confuse the OP with that...

Comment: @arshajii OP wants _with out the if ... else clause_. I hope it'll compile. What's the problem with this?

Comment: int Mazenumber = myScannerinput.nextInt();
         String fileName = "maze"+Mazenumber+".txt";
         Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

Comment: @ClearMist It is a good practice in stackoverflow to close the question if you've got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You define and initialise myScanner inside the if block, so it will be out of scope as soon as you leave it

Comment: His code compiles. The variable declared within the if-statements shadows another variable in the outer scope.

Comment: @arshajii The variable that the value is assigned to gets out of scope, whatever other variable (not shown in given code anyway) never gets a value.